# Get Ember Data working with array of objects

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data

I have a simple Ember Data app to list and show various objects.

My `/servers.json` API (for example) return this kind of format:

```
[
   {
      "hosted_domain" : "example.com",
      "status" : 1,
      "name" : "srv0443",
      "id" : 443
   },
   {
      "id" : 392,
      "status" : 1,
      "name" : "srv0392",
      "hosted_domain" : "example.com"
   },
   {
      "hosted_domain" : "example.com",
      "id" : 419,
      "name" : "srv0419",
      "status" : 1
   }
]
```

But I got the following error:

```
Assertion Failed: The response from a findAll must be an Array, not undefined
```

Ember Data expects this kind of format:

```
{
   "servers" : [
      {
         "name" : "srv0443",
         "status" : 1,
         "id" : 443,
         "hosted_domain" : "example.com"
      },
      {
         "status" : 1,
         "name" : "srv0392",
         "id" : 392,
         "hosted_domain" : "example.com"
      },
      {
         "status" : 1,
         "name" : "srv0419",
         "hosted_domain" : "example.com",
         "id" : 419
      },
  ]
}
```

I know I can override the payload with the [extractArray](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_extractArray) of the `RESTSerializer`.

It's works by doing `payload = { servers: payload }` but how get it working in a generic way?

How can I do to catch the needed key of an model type?

In a more general way, what is the good REST format, by convention?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution by using `primaryType.typeKey` and [ember-inflector](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-inflector) tool on the RESTSerializer:

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend
  extractArray: (store, primaryType, payload) ->
    # Payload reload with { type.pluralize: hash }
    payloadKey = Ember.Inflector.inflector.pluralize primaryType.typeKey
    payloadReloaded = []
    payloadReloaded[payloadKey] = payload

    @_super store, primaryType, payloadReloaded
```

In a nutshell:

- Get the type key (e.g. server)
- Pluralize it (e.g. server**s**)
- Add it as payload master key (e.g. `{ servers: payload }`

And that's it!

Please feel free to comment this solution if you have a better proposition.

Answer (score 0):

Ember Data works by having the data follow a certain convention ({servers: payload}).  So the data either needs to conform, or you have to extend the serializer as you mentioned (or some other customization like overriding the model's findAll() method).  There isn't anyway around it, if you want to use Ember Data.  Of course, you don't have to use Ember Data.  Here is a good article about not using it: http://eviltrout.com/2013/03/23/ember-without-data.html

To customize the serializer you can extend it like this:
    `App.ServerSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
      extractArray: function(store, type, payload) {
        this._super(store, type, {servers: payload});
      },
    });`

Extract array is automatically called by ember after it gets a response from the server. This will put in the format ember data expects, then pass it on to continue processing as usual. But you will have to do that for each type of model.  If you override App.ApplicationSerializer instead you might be able to use the type paramter to figure out which key should go in the modified payload, so it will work for any model, but I can't check it right now.

Comment: Thanks for help and the link. But my question is exactly about how to override the serializer to adapt it with the returned data.

Comment: Oh ok, I thought you were trying to avoid doing that.  I edited the answer to include how to do that.

Comment: Yes I knew this solution but is specific for Server model. I have dozens of model and controllers, it will be painful to override each one. I'm looking for a generic way by getting the needing key (`servers` in this case). Did you get it? Thanks for help btw.